# How to access values with html tags from json using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-collapsible

am having one task phonegap like parse the values from json using jquery and show it in collapisble.i can able parse to parse the value i dont know how to parse it in jquery mobile collapsible.mycode is given below:

```
$.each(data.results, function(k, v){ 
    $('.description').html(v.Maincontent);
    //here am get full values so i want to display ul li values in collapsible 
});
```

```html
<div data-role="collapsible"> <h3></h3> </div>
```

in `<h3>`--i want to show the ptag value from json. when user click on p tag means i want to show the `li` values from `json`.

```
     Json value: {
    "results": [
        {
            "Name": "test content",
            "Id": "1429",
            "Title": "Test",
            "dMain-Screen": "Test sub title",

            "diningMainContent": "<p>sample test content</p>\n<p></p>\n<p>Pizza</p>\n<ul>\n<li>Chicken</li>\n<li>BBQ</li>\n<li>Onion Mushroom</li>\n</ul>\n<p>Pasta</p>\n<ul>\n<li>Sample</li>\n<li>sample1</li>\n<li>sample2</li>\n</ul>\n<p>Testing</p>\n<ul>\n<li>one</li>\n<li>two</li>\n<li>three</li>\n</ul>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CDATA tags around your HTML in the service that returns your json.

```
<![CDATA[ ***your content goes here*** ]]>
```

Though a better way to do it would to only have the json return values (instead of html strings) and build the HTML you need inside your function. That would require a change to your JSON and your function but you gain more in the long run (bandwidth, maintainability, reusability).